# Could sufficiently powerful Diamagnetism be used to repel a light macro-sized object above the ground?

Tags: electromagnetism

Take, for example, a futuristic-looking square "lamp" (effectively a metal cube that emits light).
Overall we assume the lamp can be made to have a mass of around ~20 grams as this is roughly equivalent to a common frog, one of which had once been levitated using diamagnetism.
Placed at the bottom of the inside of the lamp is the magnet giving the diamagnetic force. Above it is a super-light rod that is pushed upwards by the magnet below at ~9.8m/s.  
 
Since the lamp is accelerating upwards at ~9.8m/s, it would appear to have zero gravity. Therefore, surely, such a system could in theory be used to create a conveniant source of lighting at all times that could simply be thrown into the air where it would sit. 
Due to the seeming convenience of such a concept I assume there are challenges preventing its creation. I can already see one of the biggest issues being the creation a small, light magnet with that level of upwards force. As well as the difficult implementation of such a light-weight power source for such a powerful magnetic. If these things could truly exist they would presumably require extremely frequent if not literally constant charging. Despite these issues, due to my basic understanding of the subject I cannot see any conceptual issues with the design. To summarise; please gimme answer! :)

Comment: Superconductors do this. In fact this property is used in maglevs. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglev

Comment: To push the light up there must be a downwards force on something. I think this will be on the magnet in the device you describe, so it will not levitate as a whole. But perhaps a diamagnetic jack-in-the-box.

Comment: @Peter I'm not exactly sure what you are saying? Is the downwards force not gravity itself? Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: Your question reads to me as describing a box containing a magnet and a diamagnetic light. The magnet pushes the diamagnetic light upwards, but there needs to be something holding up the box. It won't hang in the air any more than a box with a spring in it. You can get the light to hang in the air, but it will only be a short distance above the magnet, which will need to be held up.